# Lambda in a attribute parameter

Tags: c#, .net, attributes, lambda

Why can't we add a lambda as attribute parameter? For example I would like to do:

```
[MyAttribut(Transform= {object => object.ToSomethingElse()})]
```

Should I understand that lambda in C# are only closure?

EDIT: By looking at all answer let me precise one things that most people seems to not know:
Lambda are literal whish is a compile time structure unless it is a closure.

Answer (score 4):

Parameters to attributes need to be compile time constants.

From MSDN - [Attribute Parameter Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177221.aspx):

> Values passed to attributes must be known to the compiler at compile time.

They are also restricted to these types:

- bool
- char, unsigned char
- short, unsigned short
- int, unsigned int
- long, unsigned long
- __int64, unsigned __int64
- float, double
- wchar_t
- char* or wchar_t* or System::String*
- System::Type ^
- System::Object ^
- enum

Comment: A lambda is a compile time constants, unless it is a closure.

Comment: `ToSomethingElse()` is a method call. It is not a compile time constant.

Comment: method call is something that is generate at compile time, why wouldn't it be a compile time constant?

Comment: One remark I rather use the term literal as for "compile time constant". Literal are by definition a compile time constant but it should remain constant even at runtime, not that not all programming language make literal a runtime constant.

Comment: @mathk - The return value from a method call is not a compile time constant.

Comment: Your comment does not change the fact that Lambda are literal. By having written a compiler for a language that support lambda I can tell you that lambda are literal. and you can do a lot of optimization when you know that you have a lambda instead of a closure.

Answer (score 4):

Attribute parameters are restricted to constant values of the following types:

- Simple types (bool, byte, char, short, int, long, float, and double)
- string
- System.Type
- enums
- object (The argument to an attribute parameter of type object must be a constant value of -  one of the above types.)
- One-dimensional arrays of any of the above types

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288454%28VS.71%29.aspx

Comment: Yes I have seen that but I just wonder why they didn't add lambda as they are also constant, see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Although you cannot do it directly, you can update your attributes at run-time.

See my answer for question [Attribute Constructor With Lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11004909/attribute-constructor-with-lambda/26144418).

There is a code sample that demonstrate the idea. This is what I use to get display name from resource without having to copy name for attribute initialization. I still have to ensure that name match in resource file. To help ensure it stay synchronized, you can do unit testing or you might create a system that does the mapping using multiple lambdas (one for property and another for resource)...