# .NET Attribute with Func<TResult> parameter

Tags: .net, methods, delegates, attributes, func

I know this surfaced many times, like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10951378/lambda-in-a-attribute-parameter) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8463657/how-do-you-put-a-func-in-a-c-sharp-attribute-annotation) question, and it is clearly written on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664615%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), but if I cannot pass a function anyhow as a parameter to an attribute, how can [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc679238%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) do it?

What am I missing here? Is it only possible for this built in attribute to have a Func< TResult > as a parameter? If it is after all possible, can it be a Func with input parameter(s) as well?

My final goal is to be able to define the function to use to serialize a property. The whole thing is runtime code-generation magic, so I don't really need trivial alternatives to do this. I do have a workaround, but using a Func would be so much easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a delegate as an argument to an attribute constructor - you just can't do so *declaratively*.

Now in this case, it's only a protected constructor anyway - so it's intended to be called from the derived classes such as [`RangeAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.rangeattribute.aspx), which will presumably supply an appropriate delegate to the base constructor.

Comment: Ah I see it.. I didn't notice the visibility. I'm sad, but thank you!